# Adicionar um novo "Android Resource Directory" no projeto

Tags: android

Olá, estou começando a pouco a trabalhar com o Android Studio.
Pois bem, tenho uma coleção de imagens que vou utilizar no meu app e estas imagens estão separadas em 3 pastas. 
Quando eu crio um novo diretório na pasta res do meu projeto, e coloco as imagens, eu não estou conseguindo pegar o identificador destas imagems.

```
this.img_atividade.setImageResource ( getResources().getIdentifier(this.name.toLowerCase () , "atividade", getPackageName()) );
```

Neste exemplo, estou buscando o id da imagem "this.name" que está dentro do diretório "atividade"... Mas não funciona, porém se eu substituir "atividade" por "drawable" e por a imagem que quero buscar lá na drawable, funciona muito bem.

Já procurei bastante sobre por aí, pelo que vi preciso conseguir referenciar isso na Classe R, porém tenho dúvidas enquanto a isso.

Obrigado!

Comment: Nao acho que você consiga criar uma pasta com nome diferente do padrão dentro do `res`. Você pode colocar essas imagens dentro do `assets`.

Comment: Fiz o que disse e deu certo. Obrigado!

Comment: Legal, vou colocar como uma resposta pra poder marcar como correta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que você não consiga colocar uma pasta com nome diferente do padrão dentro de `res`.

O que você pode fazer é colocar essas imagens dentro de `assets`, lá você é livre para renomear a pasta como queira.